# Count and Display Data on label using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, telerik, label, radgrid

I'm using `telerik:Radgrid` and column which contains these sample `values`

```
Column 1
Female
Male
Female
Female
Male
```

The result must be displayed using the labels.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="totalFandM" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="totalF" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="totalM" />
```

How can I display the values on the label using jquery?
It should display like this.

```
totalFandM - 5 
totalF - 3
totalM - 2
```

items on radgrid

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Status" DataField="Gender"
                    UniqueName="Gender">
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbGender" runat="server"
                                SelectedValue='<%# ((GridItem)Container).OwnerTableView.GetColumn("Gender").CurrentFilterValue %>'>
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Male" Value="Male" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Female" Value="Female" />
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Comment: You should provide the generated html of "telerik:Radgrid"... i.e Column 1
Female
Male
Female
Female
Male

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your generated HTML is

```
    <li>Female</li><li>Male</li><li>Female</li><li>Female</li><li>Male</li>
```

then
       $(li).length 
will give you the totalFandM

```
   $(li:contains('Female')).length
```

will give you totalF

```
   $(li:contains('Male')).length
```

will give you totalM

Comment: I asked for generated HTML (see page source) not the code you are using.